# In Amazon Data Pipeline, how to make sure only once instance of a pipeline is running at any time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a pipeline with two tasks. Task 2 depends on Task 1 and maxActiveInstances is set to 1 for both tasks. Despite this dependency, under certain circumstances, Task 2 runs at the same time as Task 1. For example, if Task 2 takes too long and the scheduled start time of the pipeline's next execution is reached, Task 1 starts running at the same time. Same thing happens in case of backfilling.

Since these two tasks interfere with each other, I don't want them to run at the same time under any circumstances. Ideally, I'd want only want instance of the pipeline (not individual tasks) to run at a time. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Here's what the pipeline looks like with uninteresting parts replaced with `...`:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "period": "15 Minutes",
      "name": "Every 15 minutes",
      "id": "DefaultSchedule",
      "type": "Schedule",
      "startAt": "FIRST_ACTIVATION_DATE_TIME"
    },
    {
      "failureAndRerunMode": "CASCADE",
      "resourceRole": "...",
      "role": "...",
      "pipelineLogUri": "...",
      "scheduleType": "cron",
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
      },
      "maxActiveInstances": "1",
      "name": "Default",
      "id": "Default"
    },
    {
      "name": "CopyTablesActivity",
      "id": "CopyTablesActivity",
      "workerGroup": "dp01",
      "type": "ShellCommandActivity",
      "command": "..."
    },
    {
      "name": "CreateReportsActivity",
      "id": "CreateReportsActivity",
      "workerGroup": "dp01",
      "type": "ShellCommandActivity",
      "command": "...",
      "dependsOn": {
        "ref": "CopyTablesActivity"
      }
    }
  ],
  "parameters": [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the CopyTablesActivity, you could set a `lateAfterTimeout` attribute to be 5 minutes or so and then add an attribute called onLateAction, and set that to terminate. The idea is if the CopyTablesActivity doesn't finish after 5 minutes, terminate the pipeline. As an example, the CopyTablesActivity object could look like so:

`{
      "name": "CopyTablesActivity",
      "id": "CopyTablesActivity",
      "workerGroup": "dp01",
      "lateAfterTimeout" : "5 minutes",
      "type": "ShellCommandActivity",
       "onLateAction" : {
            "ref" : "DefaultAction1"
        }
      "command": "..."
    }`

And then, you could define DefaultAction1 as such:

`{
  "name" : "TerminateTasks",
  "id" : "DefaultAction1",
  "type" : "Terminate"
}`

See this link for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-terminate.html

Comment: I know about that, but it doesn't quite address the problem for me. Occasionally (but not often), that task takes a long time to run. I don't want to kill it after 5 minutes.

Comment: It looks like you have it set to run every 15 minutes. When you say occasionally the task takes longer than 5 minutes to run, how much longer?  What you could do is have a column called processing in a log table, which you set to true before the CopyTablesActivity runs, via another object, then after CreateReportsActivity runs, you could set it to false, via another object. If processing is equal to true during that first object, you could either wait a specific amount of time or cancel the pipeline.

Comment: I wouldn't want to do that as part of the current activities, because in case they get killed (for whatever reason) I'll have to update that state column manually (I was thinking an S3 object instead of a db column). Is there a way to have a pipeline condition that cancels the whole run if an S3 object exists? Then I can have two activities that add (at the start) and delete (at the end) that object.

Comment: You could have a shellCommandActivity object ping s3 via the aws cli to see if the object exists. As for failing the entire pipeline based on a condition, I recently asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302814/how-to-fail-a-shellcommandactivity-on-aws-data-pipeline/49645154#49645154 and someone made a suggestion, I haven't had a chance to test it yet, but it may work.

Comment: @lfk did you find answer to this question. I'm running 33 pipelines on long running EC2 and facing same issue.

Comment: @FarhanS I don't think I did, and I found Amazon Data Pipeline a poor choice for workflow management and used Airflow instead in future projects.